# How to turn off "untrusted location" warning for a digital-signed exe running from a network share

Tags: windows-7, uac

I feel this quite annoying. On my Windows 7 SP1 machine, when I want to run a digital-signed exe(as Administrator) from a network share, Windows shows me an **orange** warning box.

[image: UAC Untrusted location warning]

But if I run the same exe from local disk, Windows show me a more friendly **blue** info box. The blue box signifies that the EXE is digitally signed.

[image: UAC digitally signed exe]

The difference between an orange box and a blue box is a very good visual way to distinguish whether an EXE is harmful or harmless. And, if an EXE is digitally signed, I think it makes NO difference whether it is from local disk or network share. So it is quite stupid to show, and see, an orange warning box for a valid digitally signed EXE. Showing an orange one lets me worry about whether that EXE has been tampered.

More disgustingly, on the very Windows 7 of mine, running a digitally-signed EXE and a not-digitally-signed EXE exhibit the SAME warning scene to user. I mean, after answering Yes to the orange box, Windows proceeds to launch the EXE, *no more* warning presented in case the EXE is not-digitally-signed or digital signature is invalid .

So, my question is: **How to have valid digitally signed EXE from network share show the blue box instead of the orange one?**

==== ANSWERED, ADD A SCREEN SHOT ====

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sledgehammer" method is to mark the entire `\\chj` fileserver as trusted. You can add it to "trusted locations" via the Internet control panel (`inetcpl.cpl`), as the Windows shell uses the same zone settings as IE.

Comment: Thanks, quite feasible. Now I can easily differentiate signed/unsigned EXEs from network share.

Comment: From my specific case, does it mean Windows fail to categorize ``\\chj`` into "Local intranet"? **Local intranet** has a even looser security setting(Medium-low) than **Trusted sites** (Medium) .